# Wifi gets automatically disabled in Ubuntu 12.04 Gnome Classic

Tags: wireless, hp-pavilion

I am using a HP dv2000 series laptop. I have a broadcom 802.11g wireless apapter installed on the machine. While surfing the internet in  Ubuntu 12.04, sometimes the Wifi gets disabled automatically. (sudo rfkill list shows that Wlan is hard locked). I have tried commands like 
sudo rfkill unblock all

But the hard lock still remains. I have to always restart my laptop to get the Wifi working again.

Any solutions to this problem?